# Saber todas as $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

Estou com uma duvida e procurei e n achei em canto nenhum uma resposta, queria saber se e possível eu dar um `echo $_SESSION`  e saber todas as `session` que meu navegador tem naquele momento e se sim como?

Comment: `print_r($_SESSION)`, `var_dump($_SESSION)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode usar `var_dump` ou `print_r`, assim:

```
<?php
session_start();

var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Ou assim:

```
<?php
session_start();

print_r($_SESSION);
```

O `print_r` é mais fácil de ler, pois contém menos detalhes, idela para quem só quer ver o conteudo mesmo, já o `var_dump` é ideal para analisar bem as variaveis, valores, como strings, int, float, tamanho e etc.

Comment: Eu citaria o `var_export` também, dada a facilidade de copiar e jogar no interpretador para testar :D

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss penso no var_export em casos aonde precisamos que mantenha uma sintaxe que poderá ser executada no proprio PHP posteriormente, por exemplo um sistema que edita variaveis de um arquivo de configuração em .php, um exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43458974/1518921 (só pra constar, o preg_replace ali é por causa da sindrome do TOC, detesto `,` no ultimo item de um array :P)

Answer (score 0):

Como o Guilherme falou acima, se você quer apenas ver, o print_r ou var_dump vai seguir. Se quiser usar na sua aplicação, é só ter em mente que pra todos os efeitos a variável $_SESSION pode ser tratada como um array comum do PHP.